# Inserting a new row within an existing excel file

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a way to insert a new row to an existing excel sheet. I looked at openxlsx package, but can't seem to find the best function to do this. The writeData function works well, but it erases the values on the row I append. Overall I'm trying to insert a row at the top of my sheet to add column titles.

I tried xlsx, but I'm getting an issue with the java version I'm running and IT isn't here to update my java. What's the best package to do this if not writeData?

Here's a general idea of what I was using. Step 1 choose wb, Step 2 add column name, Step 3 save.

```
library(openxlsx)
    wb <-loadWorkbook("first.xlsx")
    writeData(wb, sheet = "Sheet 3", rev.default("Tango"), colNames = F, 
    borders = "columns", 
              borderStyle = "medium")
    saveWorkbook(wb,"first.xlsx",overwrite = T)
```

Comment: Could you first read the sheet into a data frame with `openxlsx::readWorkbook("first.xlsx", colNames=F)`, then add colnames to the data frame, and then write that back to the xlsx with `writeData()`?

Comment: @CasparV. I'll try and see if I can add a new row that way, good idea. Do you know if there's an easier way to read a df for a wb with multiple sheets? I'm still kind of struggling how I could edit each one individually before writing it.

Comment: You can get a character vector of all sheet names with `getSheetNames()`, and iterate over that. A simple for-loop or apply-call would get the job done.

Comment: @CasparV. using a vector did the trick, thanks!